# Order is not getting generated at magento 2.3 but payment successfully done paypal

Tags: magento2

Have a look at the problem here. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25550

```
Preconditions (*)
```

Magento 2 upgrade from Magento 2.2.6 to 2.3.2
Paypal express method
Steps to reproduce (*)
create any customer with Magento 2.2.*
upgrade the Magento 2.2.* to Magento 2.3.2
enable Paypal express checkout
Expected result (*)
order should be recorded in Magento 2.3.2 backend
Actual result (*)
customer is charged properly.
payment deducted from their account and deposited to client's account
No order found in the backend and that order id skip
This is a very terrible case, The version upgrade should ease the user experience and of course the developer but it shouldn't introduce a new bug or errors.

I had made a dip dive into the code base and here is the process of how PayPal checkout happen.

SetExpressCheckout
GetExpressCheckoutDetails
DoExpressCheckoutPayment
I suspect the following from the core file and log files that.

GetExpressCheckoutDetails doesn't get a SHIPTOPHONENUM when order are recorded in the backend but charged
In addition to this, I have also come to know that 3. DoExpressCheckoutPayment is not sending an email and phone number data in the array and sending null instead.

The following exception might be the cause of the above

We can't save the address: Email has a wrong format

We are getting a lot of orders through PayPal express too and it's not a constant issue but we are having a problem with 1 to 2 orders a day and mostly happen with old customer account ( which was done while with Magento 2.2.6)

I am looking for any thoughts on this from an expert developer and Magento core team what potential causes would be there apart from my analysis.

Let me know your thought and any quick help will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Sam

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: You can upgrade your Magento version to the latest one. Then either disable the papal express checkout from the shopping cart or just do code edit to redirect the customer to checkout page even when they click on PayPal express checkout button on shopping page.

Comment: got the solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310068/email-address-has-a-wrong-format-error-on-paypal-express-checkout-magento-2-3-2/310254#310254