# Email address has a wrong format error, on paypal express checkout Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, email, paypal-express

Paypal Express checkout not working, it says "Exception message: We can't save the address:
Email has a wrong format". However payments are being successful but Magento order isn't creating.
Anyone?

```
Exception message: We can't save the address:
Email has a wrong format
Trace: <pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->save() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Model/AbstractModel.php:655]
```

[image]

I checked in this file `vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Address/Validator.php`
and $address->getEmail() is coming NULL/empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved with this patch https://nimb.ws/gFA06i

[image]

Here is the code in non-image format:

```
    /* set customer email if email is found empty (bug) */
    if ($this->_quote->getCustomerEmail() === null && $this->_quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail() !== null) {
        $this->_quote->setCustomerEmail($this->_quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail());
    }
```

Comment: Any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/325882/57334 thanks @Arsalan Ul Haq