# Magento 2.3 can't place order with Paypal All-In-One

Tags: magento2.3, payment, paypal

I've updated Magento from `2.2.7 to 2.3.5-p1` and now with the `Paypal All-In-One` order payment, something's not right.

It's all good until the payment part at PayPal website, you confirm the payment and the payment is accepted by PayPal but when you're supposed to go to the order success page it goes out and in the `system.log` appears:

```
main.CRITICAL: The following tag(s) are not allowed: img [] []
```

Then the order appears in the quote table in the database with the increment_id reserved but the **order is not created**.

What can cause this?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it took me a while,
first the tag isn't a problem with Paypal or the payment, it's not related with the problem, I taught it was but no.

Now the real problem, is caused by a bug
[Email address has a wrong format error, on paypal express checkout Magento 2.3.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/310068/email-address-has-a-wrong-format-error-on-paypal-express-checkout-magento-2-3-2/310254#310254)
This solved the problem even in Magento 2.3.5-p1!

Thanks, hope it helps someone :D